# AJAX not notice change inside the file

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a .pls (playlist) file on localhost and I read this file with AJAX:

```
var myPlaylist = (!XMLHttpRequest) ?new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
:new XMLHttpRequest;
myPlaylist.open( "GET", tempsrc,true);
myPlaylist.onreadystatechange = reportStatus;
```

`reportStatus` method splits `responseText` and sends links to the video player.

When I make a change and update my .pls file, which is referred as `tempsrc` in the code, my program works on old version of the file and ignores changes I made on file.
If I rename the .pls file, then it notices changes and treats it like a new file which makes sense.

What can I do to make it notice changes without renaming the .pls file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect your web browser is caching the HTTP request.  You can explicitly avoid this by adding the current time as a useless parameter to the URL:

```
myPlaylist.open( "GET", tempsrc + '?_=' + (new Date()).getTime(),true);
```

Note that this presumes that there are no parameters already being passed. If there are, change the `?` to an `&`.